# Firebase post method block function not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

here is my code when some try to access post method via GET method i want to show some error

here is my code

```
exports.createScream = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) =>{
   // if (req.method !== "POST" ) {
   //     return res.status(400).json({error: `method not allowed`})
   // }
   if(req.method != 'POST'){   
       return res.status(400).json({error:'bad request method not allowed'})   
   }

   const newScream  = {
       body: req.body.body,
       userHandle: req.body.userHandle,
       createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
   }
   admin.firestore()
       .collection("screams")
       .add(newScream)
       .then((doc) => {
           res.json({message: `document ${doc.id} created successfully`})
       })
       .catch(err => {
           res.status(500).json({error: `someing went wrong`});
           console.error(err)
       })
})
```

someone can you correct me why

```
 if(req.method !== 'POST'){ 
        return res.status(400).json({error:'bad request method not allowed'})   
    }
```

this spece of code is not working ?

Comment: what is the error ??

Comment: its print html error my expected is i want to see `'bad request method not allowed`

Comment: where is the router ?? it seem code is not correct.. can u add more code here.. like how u create a route and call this `createScream`

Comment: i just follow the firebase doc when i call post method its work fine but when i change as GET and send its wont throw custom error

Comment: you check, i think depends on config, this method get called only in POST